# According to Hebrews 1:4 when did Jesus become superior to angels and become a son?

Tags: hebrews, christology

According to Hebrews 1:4 Jesus became superior to the angels and received a new title, "son" that was superior to the title "angel":

> NIV Hebrews 1: 4So he **became** as much superior to the angels as the
>   name [title - "son"] he has inherited is superior to theirs. 5For to
>   which of the angels did God ever say, “You are my Son; **today I have
>   become your Father”**? Or again, “I will be his Father, and he will be
>   my Son”?

Does this indicate that prior to his incarnation he was not higher than the angels and was not yet God's son?

Comment: Should the answers be directed to your questions (which are assumptions)  or you need an explanation of the text what it would mean.

Answer (score 1):

> *According to Hebrews 1:4, **when did Jesus become superior to angels** and become a son ?*

Let's do this interactively :

1. Would you agree that the idea expressed (twice) in verse 4 is the same as the one contained in the latter half of verse 9 ?
2. Would you agree that verse 9 is immediately followed by verse 10 ?
3. Would you agree that the two ideas expressed in verses 9<sup>b</sup> and 10 are the exact same as the ones mentioned earlier, in the exact same order, in the latter half of verse 2 ?
4. Would you agree that *the aeons* of verse 2 and *the heavens* of verse 10 include *the angels* mentioned throughout the first two chapters ?
5. Would you agree that, following the 5<sup>th</sup> commandment, children are to honor their parents ?
6. Would you agree that the worship mentioned at the end of verse 6 is a form of honor ?
7. Would you agree that, in light of 7:7, the one being honored and worshiped is greater than the ones doing the honoring and the worshiping ?

If so, then what logical conclusions are we to draw from all this ?

---

> *According to Hebrews 1:4, **when did Jesus** become superior to angels and **become a son** ?*

Let's do this interactively :

1. Would you agree that a statement is to be primarily interpreted in light of its surrounding context ?
2. Would you agree that both the first and the last third of verse 2 equate *the Son* with God's word ?
3. Would you agree that the utterer and the utterance relate to one another as a parent to a child ?

If so, then what logical conclusions are we to draw from all this ?

Comment: @Ruminator: Any attempt or endeavor in trying to answer that question is ripe with speculation, since it invites various references to other biblical works, not written by the same author (Genesis, Psalms, Gospels, Acts, and Revelation, among others), for which reason I have intentionally avoided tackling it, and have purposefully restrained myself to choosing the path in need of the least possible number of extracurricular assumptions.

Comment: Though not mandatory, explanations for (down)votes are certainly welcome and helpful.

Comment: @Ruminator: Since I am indeed a Trinitarian, I shall offer here three observations: (1). Your initial, unedited question emphasized verse 4. (2). My “trinitatrian” answer, believe it or not, contradicts neither Arianism, nor Nestorianism. (3). I genuinely wasn't joking when I wrote that *any attempt or endeavor in trying to answer that question is ripe with speculation, since it invites various references to other biblical works, not written by the same author (Genesis, Psalms, Gospels, Acts, and Revelation, among others)*.

Comment: @Ruminator: I am saying that, from a strictly hermeneutic perspective, the question admits several equally valid but completely distinct answers.

Comment: @Ruminator: In this particular case, I don't think that it is possible to exactly establish which of the word's (three) possible meanings is intended; even the literal meaning could have at least three possible interpretations, as far as I am able to see: and I am not just saying this because I am trinitarian. :-)

Comment: If I don't get a satisfactory answer I'll have a stab at it.

Comment: @Ruminator: May I suggest doing it in another question ? (I ask this because, in my opinion, it constitutes a “beast” in its own right).

Answer (score 1):

Jesus (The Word) when on earth was a human son of God via the virgin the birth, God was his father.
At his baptism he was born again as a spiritual son of God which God told him at that time.

ethos

Answer (score 0):

Answer: in eternity past. "Being made (having become) so much better than the angels, as he hath 'by inheritance obtained' (by being assigned as family heir) a more excellent name than they."

Per Vines Expository Dictionary of Greek NT words, KLERONOMEO; "birthrite, that into the possession of which on enters in virtue of sonship not because of a price paid or a task completed."

Hence the sonship was part of the divine relationship from eternity past for we know that Christ died for us before the foundation of the world.

This specific question falls into the area of doctrine (deity of Christ) and subject to interpretation hence most likely the reason the question was voted down.

Comment: It is an exegetical question. Your answer is a doctrinal/dogma answer but the question itself is asking what a particular text is saying, not what a Council decided. Can you answer the question without resorting to a dogma?