Is this Hebrews 1:2-3 translation a legitimate translation purely from a grammatical standpoint

2 In these last days he has spoken to us in his Son, whom he appointed the heir of all things and through whom he created the ages. He being the radiance of the glory and the exact expression of his confidence and bringing [about] all things in the word of his power -- purification for the sins having accomplished -- he sat down at the right of the Majesty on High"  -Hebrews 1:2-3

Please note that I'm asking strictly about Greek grammar and whether this is a legitimate translation.
I am not asking whether it is the correct translation.
And I am not asking for anything about doctrine or any implications of that translation.

Those are some dense verses - which part are you asking about in particular? It might be better to ask separate questions about each feature.

I find the question difficult.  You word the question in "strict" terms of "Greek grammar" and yet you also ask it in terms of "translation."  But you don't provide a mapping between the two (which would make for a very large question!).  To make concrete my comment, here's one example:  I don't know what "spoken ... in his Son" means.  In English, what could "speak in another person" mean?  It can't mean what the Greek means since it has no meaning in English. English uses 'by'.  If your intent is to expose the Greek, then that's a hermeneutics tool (a good thing), but, not IMO a translation.

@MikeSangrey, I believe there are different translation philosophies. Some are more word for word and others are more interpretive. I prefer something closer to word for word as I don't fully trust translators to do much interpretation. This also forces the reader to better understand the idioms and reference of that time and biblical tradition. Regarding what it means for God to speak in his son, I believe it means that God has spoken to us via the leadership and guidance of His son where previously we were spoken to us via the leadership & guidance of the earlier prophets like Moses & Abram.

Getting into a discussion of translation philosophies would take us way too far field, especially in a comment section.  My comment about not knowing the meaning of "speak in his son" was in reference to the English, not the Greek.  The English has no meaning.  One has to interpret the English as if one is reading the Greek.  And that is why I said that such renderings are not a translation.  One has to back-translate them into Greek, or individualistically redefine the English, in order to actually interpret the text so as to arrive at the meaning.

@MikeSangrey, I think it makes since in English if you understand what the Bible means by "in" in this context. I also think it conveys more information than simply saying "by." I'm not sure if it's more a Greek word definition issue or simply an issue of understanding how the Bible conceptualizes the concept of "in" with respect to a person.

It is a piece of the Bible that deserves to be a detailed grammar.
(I have marked with an asterisk the words I comment below)
Text and grammar
Verse 2
2 ἐπ’ ἐσχάτου τῶν ἡμερῶν τούτων ἐλάλησεν ἡμῖν *ἐν υἱῷ, ὃν ἔθηκεν κληρονόμον πάντων, δι’ οὗ καὶ ἐποίησεν τοὺς αἰῶνας
• ἐπ’ ἐσχάτου τῶν ἡμερῶν τούτων › 1) preposition (upon): ἐπί + ἔσχατον :adjective of the neuter (of the last), in the Genitive case; means: upon (of) the last. 2) τῶν ἡμερῶν τούτων; article Genitive plural: ἡ + ἡμέρα :noun plural Genitive feminine, + αὕτη :pronoun indicative, Genitive plural feminine gender; means: upon (of) the last of these days. Here the “ἐπ᾿ ἐσχάτου” together with the “τῶν ἡμερῶν τούτων”, upon the last of these days, means, of the last events that happened on these days, i.e., the recent, a hot event.
• ἐλάλησεν ἡμῖν ἐν υἱῷ › verb in the 3rd person definite infinitive active voice: λαλέω > λαλῶ + ἡμεῖς :1st person Dative plural personal pronoun = to us, + ἐν :Dative preposition in/with/by etc, + υἱῷ :Dative singular noun = son; means: he spoke to us by the Son.
• ὃν ἔθηκεν › 3rd person singular Accusative case pronoun: ὅς + τίθημι :verb aorist 3rd person singular indicative inclination active voice; means: whom he put on.
• κληρονόμον πάντων › noun masculine singular Accusative: κληρονόμος + πᾶς :adjective of the neuter plural Genitive = of all; means: heir of all.
• δι᾿ οὗ καὶ ἐποίησεν τοὺς αἰῶνας › preposition (for/because/through/disjunctive) + ὅς :3rd person Genitive singular pronoun = of him, + καί (and/also/as well) + ποιέω > ποιῶ :3rd person singular indicative inclination active verb aorist = he had made, + ὁ :plural Accusative article, + αἰών : noun masculine accusative plural = eras; means: through which (of him) he had made, as well, the eras (as we say, "the era of creation, the era of the first men, the era of Noah, of Abraham and his sons, the era of David and his son Solomon, the era of the resettlement of Jewish prisoners in Babylon, the era of Aramean speaking, the era of Jesus Christ and the New Testament, and he continues).
Verse 3
3 ὃς ὢν *ἀπαύγασμα τῆς δόξης καὶ χαρακτὴρ τῆς ὑποστάσεως αὐτοῦ, φέρων τε τὰ πάντα τῷ ῥήματι τῆς δυνάμεως αὐτοῦ, καθαρισμὸν τῶν ἁμαρτιῶν ποιησάμενος ἐκάθισεν ἐν δεξιᾷ τῆς μεγαλωσύνης ἐν ὑψηλοῖς
• ὃς ὢν ἀπαύγασμα τῆς δόξης › 3rd person singular relative pronoun Nominative: ὅς + ὤν :singular participle of the verb "εἰμί" which means "I am"; translated: who being... + ἀπαύγασμα :noun of the neuter singular = the absolute expression of, + ἡ :article of the feminine singular Genitive, + δόξα :noun of the feminine Genitive = glory; means: who, being the absolute expression of the glory.
• καὶ χαρακτὴρ τῆς ὑποστάσεως αὐτοῦ › conjunction: καί + χαρακτήρ :noun nominative singular masculine = the clear characterization, + ἡ :article genitive feminine, + ὑπόστασις :noun genitive feminine singular = of the nature of, + αὐτός :definite pronoun genitive singular masculine = of him; means: and the clear characterization of his nature.
• φέρων τε τὰ πάντα τῷ ῥήματι τῆς δυνάμεως αὐτοῦ › singular Nominative participle: φέρω + τέ :conjunction composed after the first word of a sentence, and means: and, + τό :plural article of the neuter Accusative, + πᾶν :neuter indefinite pronoun plural Accusative = everything, + τό : article neuter Dative, + ῥῆμα :noun neuter singular Dative = with/by the word, + ἡ :article Genitive singular, + δύναμις :noun Genitive singular feminine = of power, + αὐτός :definite pronoun Genitive singular 3rd person = of him; means: and bearing everything by the word of his power.
• καθαρισμὸν τῶν ἁμαρτιῶν ποιησάμενος › noun Accusative singular masculine: καθαρισμός + ἡ :article feminine plural Genitive, + ἁμαρτία :noun feminine plural Genitive = of sins, + ποιέω > ποιῶ :participle aorist passive voice of this verb = he has been the victim (in the act of the sufferings), He did (the victim causing the purification of the sins).
• ἐκάθισεν ἐν δεξιᾷ τῆς μεγαλωσύνης ἐν ὑψηλοῖς › verb in 3rd person aorist singular indicative inclination: καθίζω + ἐν :preposition Dative, + δεξιά :adjective feminine singular Dative, + ἡ :article singular Genitive feminine, + μεγαλωσύνη :noun feminine singular Genitive = of majesty, + ἐν :preposition Dative, + ὑψηλόν :adjective neuter plural Dative = (on) high. Meaning: He sat (down) on (the) right (hand) of majesty on high.
strict translation
On the last of these days, He spoke to us by (the) Son, whom He appointed heir of all (things), through which (of Him) He had made, as well, the eras; which (He) being (the) absolute expression of the Glory and (the) clear characterization of the Nature (of Him), since He had made purification of (the) sins, He sat down on (the) right (hand) of the Majesty on high.
Free translation
Just before these days, He spoke to us by the Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom He also made the eras; who, being the absolute expression of the Glory and the clear characterization of His Nature, having made purification of sins, sat down on the right hand of the Majesty on high.
Comments
*ἐν υἱῷ › this particular case is the Instrumental (an ancient case that was merged into Dative). The common translation that all translations usually render it is the Instrumental instrument, which indicates that God spoke through the Son, or using the Son. But there is also the Instrumental mode, which, in my opinion, is the one that should be applied. That is, as if we were answering the question: how did God speak to us? "by the Son" (mode). To the question of instrument, we ask the following question: with whom did God speak to us? "by the Son". The translation is the same, it does not change. The reason, perhaps, why it is preferable to use the Instrumental mode, is that the concept of God in the Son as the primary agent of the existence of all things and events is not questioned.
*ἀπαύγασμα › from "ἀπό + αὔγος/αὐγή > ἀπαύγασμα / ἀπαυγάζω < ἀπό + αὐγάζω. Αὐγάζω = I begin to appear shining on high = sun; the dawn of the sun. Ἀπαυγάζω = to send my rays outward/downward (radiate); and by extension metaphorically: to send the kind of my light, the being of my light.

I decided to look at this, after you brought up self same verses in our "Chat Room" conversation. You might have noticed that I have already been active here. See my comments under Alex's answer. In fact just 2 months ago I answered a Q that included Heb, 1:2 thru 6:- https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30366/according-to-hebrews-12-5-when-did-jesus-become-superior-to-angels-and-become-a/98252#98252  ... but that wasn't answered grammatically. From what I can tell, you've answered Austin's Q admirably. Not sure why he hasn't, yet at least, given you favor. It's an upvote from me.

@OldeEnglish watch the chat room

The word translated as "in" used in Heb. 1:1-3 is Strong's G1772, "en" and denotes

denotes a position within a space or time, but it can also indicate means or instrumentality. It is often used to express the idea of being in a particular state or condition, or being in association or union with someone or something. The preposition can also imply agency or means, as in being "by" or "with" something. (Biblehub)

Young's Literal Translation closely follows the Greek.

1 In many parts, and many ways, God of old having spoken to the fathers in the prophets, 2 in these last days did speak to us in a Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He did make the ages; 3 who being the brightness of the glory, and the impress of His subsistence, bearing up also the all things by the saying of his might -- through himself having made a cleansing of our sins, sat down at the right hand of the greatness in the highest,  (Heb. 1:1-3, YLT)

The usage of "in" is literally correct when we recognize that the word of God, the message from God was put into the prophets' mouths.  God's words were not filtered through the minds of the prophets but were put into their mouths as if they became a megaphone.  In the same manner His son told the people that what Jesus spoke came from the Father (John 7:16; 8:42; 12:49; 14:10, 24; 17:8).
God put His words in the mouths of the prophets and in the mouth of His son.  So, it is grammatically correct as translated "he has spoken to us in His son".
Just as it is grammatically correct to recognize "In these last days..." were the days in which Jesus spoke God's words to the people which happened in the first century AD during His 3-1/2 year ministry on earth.  And after having accomplished the purification of sins, or "having made a cleansing of our sins" He sat down at the right hand of the Father.  So, after His crucifixion, He sat down at the right hand of the Father "in these last days" of the first century AD.  The grammar is correct.

Having already invested in comments regarding this Q., one just moments ago, I decided to give your A., a read. It would seem that you have at least partially answered the OP, but what I truly like is your last paragraph, where you, rightly IMO, put the last days, referenced here, in the first century AD, whereas most would put them within and around the "2nd Advent", including many a theologian. It's another upvote fro me .... getting to be a habit.

@OldeEnglish - Thx.  Look forward to finding more we have in common.

God made the ages through (dia) the son (as an instrument). Consider, if all things were made through (dia) the "Word" John 1:3, that means they were not made by (Upo) him. The "Word"/son is not the primary cause of creation, it is the God of the son.
Examining the words translated from Greek using Bible hub, I didn't not find any bias or any word that is mistranslated.thus, I consider it a legitimate translation of Hebrews 1:2-3.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but have we not clashed before on the question of who made the world?? I, myself, see God as the "Architect" and the only begotten son as his "Contractor", but I'm not sure whether you, yourself, see it that way. I just recently upvoted your "locked" posting, where comments, at least for the time being, have been closed, but am reserving a possible positive acknowledgement here, pending clarification.

@OldeEnglish. By the world, do you mean ages? Jesus ascribed creation to Mark 13:19. 2 Peter 3:5 ascribes creation to God. Nothing is said about Jesus as His contractor. Isaiah 44:24. Psalm 102:25, Hebrews 1:10 -12 the heavens are the work of of YHWH's hands. Hebrews 2:7 says You made him a little lower than angels; you crowned him with glory and honor, and appointed him over the works of your hands. Creation is the work of YHWH's hands, not Jesus'.

In the NASB (Ryrie's Study Bible) he uses the word "world", but in his notes he says:- Lit., the ages, including time, space, and the material world - The contractor designation is an implication, derived from John 1:3 and Proverbs 8:30 and elsewhere. Ryrie, who I don't always agree with BTW, even states in his notes to Heb, 1:10-12 - Quoting Ps. 102:25-27. Christ is the Creator of all things and the One who, in the midst of change, is unchanging. - Contradictions, seemingly at least, abound of course, as you point out. Consequently, we will have to agree to disagree, I guess.

@OldeEnglish. No problem. I see it very plainly. Jesus' own words and carefully examining whose hands work the creation. Reread Psalm 102:25, Hebrews, 1:10 and Hebrews 2:7, and asked yourself whose hands work the creation. That is why Jesus plainly attributed creation to God..I am willing to study your "contractor" view if you educate me further,. But be advised, I prefer explicit and plain statements over assumptions based on a text that is ambiguous.

@OldeEnglish. I'm glad you said that you don't always agree with that version of the scriptures. The truth about  Psalm 102:25 - 27 does not change when it is quoted in Hebrews 1:10.

@OldeEnglish I just happen to see what you said about God being the architect and Jesus as the contractor. As it happens it is Jesus who is the architect. Revelation 3:14, The Amen, the faithful and the true Witness, the Beginning of the creation of God, says this." The Greek word for "beginning" is "arche." We get our English word "architect" from that word. "arche" means origin which means Jesus is the origin of creation. This verse is NOT teaching that God created Jesus as the JW's state. Architects do the designing or he is the origin of anything. The word "arche" is also used at Rev. 21:6

@Mr.Bond - At this time I am miles away from home and therefore not privy to all my extenuating knowledge, notes, etc... Nevertheless, suffice it to say, the beginning of the "creation" of God, becomes clearer when one considers the apostle John's prologue, where we see that Jesus' pre existence, or indeed pre eminence, in the spiritual personage of God's Logos/Word, get's his introduction, in that he is perceived as the Only Begotten of God, divinity thereby being assured. God's "special", if not "initial" creation.

OK - here is my translation of Heb 1:2, 3 -

in these last days, He has spoken to us by [the] Son whom He appointed
heir of all through whom He made the world/universe; who being [the]
radiance of glory, the exact copy of the substance of Him, then
upholding all by the word of the power by Himself, having made
purification for sins, he sat down at [the] right of the majesty on
high.

By way of comparison, here is the translation of the BLB:

in these last days has spoken to us in His Son, whom He appointed
heir of all things, and through whom He made the ages, who, being
the radiance of His glory and the exact expression of His substance, and upholding all things by the power of His word, through
having made the purification of sins, sat down at the right hand
of the Majesty on high,


Hi Dottard. Thanks for responding. I hope that people would answer the question as to whether the OP translation is a legitimate translation solely based on the rules of Greek grammar.

@Austin - unless you want a complete parsing and discussion of each grammatical choice, you will need to be more specific in your question.  Are there specific words you are asking about?
